# Is there a way to get count based on multiple columns but still have it be distinct in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, aggregate, distinct

I have included two pictures that are in Excel just for ease of viewing but I am doing the queries in SQL.

[image: Raw Data result]

[image: Desired result]

Hopefully, this is possible as the algorithm I have is not giving me the correct results.

Comment: Can you please explain why [12/17/2019] has 5 distinct "rows"? It seems to me it is 6 distinct "rows".

Comment: @jyao Sorry 12/7/19 should have 6 edited the picture to reflect

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I understand the problem, but if you first pick distinct rows, and then count number of rows per date

```
select dt, count(1)
from (
    select distinct dt, job, title, name
    from t
) as x
group by dt
```

I used dt instead of date since it is a reserved word

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure what you are asking, but I think you would want to concatenate the other columns you have into one string. then you group by the date, and count the distinct concatenated fields.

In the below i dump to a temp table first to make it easier to read, but you can do it all in one.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #X 
SELECT 
Date,
Job + ' ' + Title + ' ' Name As NewColumn
INTO #X 
FROM 
YourTable


SELECT 
Date,
COUNT(DISTINCT NewColumn) AS CNT 
FROM 
#X
GROUP BY
Date
```

Comment: If you use this approach, you must take care that the separator you choose doesn't appear in the data.  If you want to be robust, consider a `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`, but at minimum it should contain some uncommon characters.

Comment: Would you know the way to collapse all the entries into 1 day like the 2nd picture. The result it gave me prints all entries in 1 day as separate count of 1 even though the count works corectly

Comment: This has merit but how you build the concatenated string is problematic. First cast them to the fixed length equivalent, then concatenate. Numerics can be right-aligned (or decimal place aligned) or zero-padded to ensure they return as fixed length.

Comment: Despite adding a space between columns in concatenation, there is a risk that columns will be ignored in count distinct. "A B", "C" and "A", "B C" will both result in "A B C". You will have to use a separator token that can never appear as a character for it to work guaranteed.

Answer (score -1):

## Hi Try with this

simulated table must be replaced by your table, I only believe it as a reference

```
 DECLARE @SimulatedTable TABLE(
    [Date] DATE,
    Job VARCHAR(5),
    Title VARCHAR(5),
    [Name] VARCHAR(5))
    
    INSERT INTO @SimulatedTable VALUES ('12/7/2019','A','B','ABA'),('12/7/2019','B','A','BAB'),('12/7/2019','A','B','ABA'),('12/7/2019','C','C','CCC'),
    ('12/7/2019','D','D','DDD'),('12/7/2019','E','E','EEE'),('12/7/2019','F','F','FFF'),('12/8/2019','G','G','GGG'),('12/9/2019','H','H','HHH')
    
    SELECT [Date],COUNT(DISTINCT Job+Title+[Name]) AS 'Distinct COUNT Based on Colums' FROM @SimulatedTable
    GROUP BY [Date]
```

Comment: A, BC and AB, C will both end up as ABC after concatenation (+), so these will be counted only once